# How to populate an Array's data from an ArrayList (Java) as a method with parameters?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

My class assignment requires me to create an array of Lamborghini objects (class already created) based on horsepower values taken from an ArrayList of Lamborghinis. So the size of the Lamborghini[] array needs to be dependent on how many ArrayList references fall within those parameters. I'm not having trouble with that part; my method is returning the correct length of array, but each object returns 'null'.

Here are a couple of tactics I've tried already:

```
public Lamborghini[] letsTryThisAgain(double lowHP, double highHP){
    ArrayList<Lamborghini> stockArray = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();
    Iterator<Lamborghini> it = inventory.iterator();

    if ((inventory.get(0) != null) || (inventory.size() != 0)){
        while (it.hasNext()){
            Lamborghini l = it.next();
                if ((l.getHorsepower() >= lowHP) &&
                     (l.getHorsepower() <= highHP)){
                    stockArray.add(new Lamborghini(l.getModelYear(), l.getModelName(), l.getHorsepower(), l.getIsRearWheelDrive()));
                }
        }
    }

    Lamborghini[] lambosHP = new Lamborghini[stockArray.size()];

    lambosHP = stockArray.toArray(lambosHP);

    return lambosHP;
}
```

and variations on the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++){
        if (inventory.get(i) != null )
        {
            if (inventory.get(i).getHorsepower() != 0.0 ){
            if ((inventory.get(i).getHorsepower() >= lowHP) &&
                     inventory.get(i).getHorsepower() <= highHP){
                    lambosHP[counter] = inventory.get(i);
                }
            }
        }
        counter ++;
    }
```

The latter appears to work until I get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException for the line lambosHP[counter] = inventory.get(i).

I would love a solution, but some explanation as to *why* it doesn't work would be even better.

Comment: what u trying to do??

`Lamborghini[] lambosHP = new Lamborghini[stockArray.size()];

    lambosHP = stockArray.toArray(lambosHP);

    return lambosHP;` do you think it will retrun array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume the problem with your approach is you are incrementing the counter variable irrespective of the condition(cars with in the desired HP) and for each value of the main Array-List of Lamborghini.
Say there are total 50 Lamborghini cars out of which only 15 fall under the desired HP condition . Now the array[] of HP desired car will have only 15 cars . But since you are incrementing the counter value you based on the main array , Your implementation will try accessing 16th posistion.

You should probably use the below approach.TIA.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++){
    if (inventory.get(i) != null )
    {
        if (inventory.get(i).getHorsepower() != 0.0 ){
        if ((inventory.get(i).getHorsepower() >= lowHP) &&
                 inventory.get(i).getHorsepower() <= highHP){
                lambosHP[counter] = inventory.get(i);
            counter++
            }
        }
    }
   // counter ++;
}
```